# ASP.NET - Export gridview data to excel and directly send a mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I'm looking some example coding to be able to whenever a page is launched he automatically exports the current gridview data to an excel-file and then attach it to a mail and send the mail.

I have an export to excel function but this function asks the user to Save or View the file and I badly need to skip this step because I want my script to be running automatically.

If someone could help me with this this will be appreciated :)

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: I already done some research ofcourse before coming to stackoverflow :) Some people are recommending to use the ASP.NET MemoryStream but I can't find really good and concrete examples. What do you guys think?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. 
Your page loads and then you have (server-side) the data you want to export and send, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know what function you're using to export the excel but if you already have the data on the server when the page loads, then you could use something like NPOI or any similar library to export to an excel and then email the file. You don't need to send it via http to the user, i.e., not prompting the user to save or view the file

Comment: Thx for the suggestion but as a simple company developer I'm not allowed to use open-source projects without asking for and giving a good reason for using them (security reasons). But thanks alot!

Comment: I understand what you mean! Just remember that MS discourages the use of the Office Interops libraries on production servers

"Microsoft strongly recommends a number of alternatives that do not require Office to be installed server-side, and that can perform most common tasks more efficiently and more quickly than Automation. Before you involve Office as a server-side component in your project, consider alternatives."

Take a look to this page, hope this helps:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this code

```
        string filename = "Test.xls"; 
        System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);

        //Get the H`enter code here`TML for the control.
        yourGrid.RenderControl(hw);
        //Write the HTML back to the browser.
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");

        Response.Write(tw.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks but the user still needs to press "Save" or "View" file with this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to save all the data in the grid to an excel file. Here is an example how you can export data to Excel.

http://zeeshanumardotnet.blogspot.com/2011/06/creating-reports-in-excel-2007-using.html

Once you have exported data to excel file, then you can email that as an attachment to any recipient. For details how to send attachment see this link:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10828/Sending-Email-with-attachment-in-ASP-NET-using-SMT

Because you do not want user to press any button so you can write both codes in Page_load event.

Comment: the part where I don't want to user to press a button is when the excelfile is generated and it prompts the user to "Save" the file or "View" the file.
But because I don't want save it nor view it (yet) I just need to attach it in a mail and then send the mail (all via aspx!) 
In previous projects I have done them seperatly but I can't seem to get both things to work without the prompting window.